# Is there a option to query data from the table that displays/stores list of query activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

Is there a option to query data from the table that displays/stores list of query activities ?

Kindly refer the image below. We want to query data from the table that usualy displays all the details of the query

[image]

Comment: There is no image?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get query data with SQL queries - you will need to utilize SSJS (or any other language that can connect with an API) for that.

Gortonington has a great article showing how to achieve that with an undocumented REST API endpoint:

**[How to interact with Query Activities via REST API](https://gortonington.com/how-to-interact-with-query-activities-via-rest-api/)**